# C# xamarin- How to get the ip address of the device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, ip, ipv4

I need to get the ipv4 address of the device without accessing external sites.

```
IPAddress[] LocalIp = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
foreach (IPAddress iP in LocalIp)
{
    if (iP.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
    {
        MachineIP = iP;
    }
}
```

returns local IP but I need to know the public IP of the device on the 3G network and when connecting to wi-fi that of wi-fi. does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> but I need to know the public IP of the device on the 3G network and when connecting to wi-fi that of wi-fi. does anyone have any suggestions?

If you would like to get the IP address of your device when connected to Wi-Fi, you can try following code:

Firstly, define interface in Form shared code.

```
 public interface IPAddressManager
{
    string GetIPAddress();
}
```

Getting ip address when device connected wifi in Android platform.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(GetAddressManager))]
namespace demo3.Droid
{
 public  class GetAddressManager : IPAddressManager
{
    string ipAddress;
    public string GetIPAddress()
    {
        WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMgr.ConnectionInfo;
        int ip = wifiInfo.IpAddress;
        ipAddress = Formatter.FormatIpAddress(ip);
        return ipAddress;
    }
}
}
```

Uisng DependencyService to get Ip Address.

```
 private void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ip = DependencyService.Get<IPAddressManager>().GetIPAddress();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but not mine helps. With this method I always get the local IP and not the public ip.

Comment: public string GetIP()
        {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                var response = client.GetAsync("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json");
                var resultString = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                string[] ipsplit = resultString.Result.Split('"');
                return ipsplit[3];} I don't want use this and i don't want create a server for my application only for resolve the IpEndpoint.

Comment: @Sisma The code that you provide can get public ip? But you also need to other way to do ?

Comment: Yes when i'm connected with the 3g phone net board It give me the public ip, for the Wi-Fi situation i'll contact the server that solve for me the ip with an if condition gived by wifi manager. If ther's a way for retrive the public ip without contact and external server it's nice ti know It.

Comment: @Sisma - did you find a solution for this ? to get the public IP Address without the connecting to any URL ?